# AuthenticateAsClient error when attempting push notification with APNs

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on push notifications (using C#) for my company's app.  I seem to have hit every issue that is possible in the process.  I finally have push notifications working, but I still have a glitch that I have not been able to figure out.

I'm using the `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` service for testing and most of the time everything works correctly.  But occasionally, I will receive `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream`.  There doesn't appear to be anything to do to correct this either.  It just continues to fail until it starts working again.  The call that randomly fails is:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(APN_SERVICE, localCertCollection, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.TLS, false);
```

According to the Apple docs, APN will close the stream if it is given a bad token, but in this case I know I am using a good token.  And I'm not sending a large number of requests - only one or two every couple of minutes.

Has anyone else run into this behavior?  Am I hitting a APN limit of some sort?  Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things were happening:

First, I had some bad logging that was receiving a NullReferenceException and was covering up the real exception.

Second, the real exception was indicating that I was attempting multiple simultaneous reads, whic h SslStream does not support.

[SslStream.BeginRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.beginread(v=vs.100).aspx)